# Change linespacing in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, line-spacing

While the entirety of my document is written with double-spacing, I would like to have my bibliography section written single-spaced. I am using report document class.

Just to be clear, I am not trying to change the spacing between different entries, rather I'm trying to change the spacing within each entry.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 19):

Are you searching for this?

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
```

Where the bibliography should appear:

```
\begingroup
\setstretch{1.0}
\printbibliography
\endgroup
```

Comment: That worked perfectly ! Thank you so much !

Comment: @YesBerry If that worked perfectly, you might as well accept that answer by clicking on the checkmark.